# Fastest order-sensitive operations

Tags: xor, arx

For any $v$ many $b$-bits vectors $(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_{v-1}) \in \{\{0, 1\}^b\}^v$, what's the ***fastest*** way to combine $\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_{v-1}$ into a single number, such that the operation is ***order-sensitive***?

E.g. say that $\hat+$ is some method of combining numbers (not necessarily addition, but we can define it however we want).  The goal is to have $\mathbf{x}_0 \hat+ \mathbf{x}_1 \hat+ \ldots \hat+ \mathbf{x}_{v-1}$ result in a unique number different than any other order, such as, $\mathbf{x}_{v-1} \hat+ \mathbf{x}_{v-2} \hat+ \ldots \hat+ \mathbf{x}_0$.

As for ***fastest***, speed is measured on general purpose CPUs.  E.g. x86-64.

---

My thought so far is:

```
b_bits_variable xor = 0;
for (i = 0; i < v; i++) {
  xor = xor ^ (xor + x_i);
}
```

where:

- `b_bits_variable` is a variable that has exactly $b$ many bits.  E.g. if $b=16$, then we may use `uint16_t` in the C programming language.
- `v` is $v$ (quantity of vectors as in question above).
- `x_i` is $\mathbf{x}_i$ (a vector among the $v$ many ones as in question above).
- `i++` $= i+1$.
- `^` is bit-wise XOR.
- `+` is addition as commonly used in programming languages, which overflows if number is larger than $2^b - 1$.  I *think* such overflow is basically modulo $2^b$ addition. I.e. `xor + x_i` $=\text{xor} + \mathbf{x}_i \mod 2^b$.

Comment: please use mathematical notation. what is uint_8t?

Comment: Unsigned integer with 8 bits.  `uint8_t` is used in C.  I thought it's common among cryptography community to speak in C since most implementations eventually boil down to optimisations in them?  Maybe I'm wrong.  Got a better way to write this?

Comment: writing the problem mathematically will make it clearer to those who do not code. What set do your variables lie in? what are the operations defined on them? rand_pick_pool means what?

Comment: Let us say I have $X_1,\ldots,X_N \in \{0,1\}^m$ so these are $m-$bit vectors. You can also think of them as integers in $\{0,1,..,2^m-1\}$ with modulo $2^m-1$ addition. Using this, re express your question.

Comment: @kodlu - IMO that's too much, because this question is about fast implementations.  IMO a subset of cryptography is closely related to implementations when it comes to performance, and my question is one.  I think too much mathematical abstraction will take us away from the goal of the question

Comment: Fair enough. *But* if you wanted to understand if there is an intrinsic reason, based on the parameters $N,m$ in my comment and the exact order of the two operations that determine whether the overall outcome's order sensitivity, that is a mathematical crypto question. I am talking about your question 1. I still don't understand what exactly is the setup, but no matter.

Comment: @kodlu - Done (thanks, you're right; I overlooked that).

Answer (score 1):

This is one simple idea.

I will use $x_i$ for the vector in $d$ dimensions and use $a_i$ for the corresponding integer
in $\{0,1,\ldots, 2^d-1\}$.

Sort the $a_i$ from small to large. Let $r_i$ be the rank of $a_i$ use ranks from
$\{0,1,\ldots,v-1\}$. Break ties arbitrarily during sorting.

Example: $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,7,2)$ has rank vector $(r_1,r_2,r_3)=(0,2,1).$ There are three entries numbered from 0 to 2 and the middle entry 7 is the largest with rank 2.

Now consider the list of permutations of 3 objects in standard lexicographic order and their index

$$
012~~0\\
021~~1\\
102~~2\\
120~~3\\
201~~4\\
210~~5\\
$$
and note that this permutation is 021 so has position 1 in the list of permutations. Encoding the position as a binary vector takes $r=\lceil \log_2 v\rceil$ bits.

If $r\leq d,$ we can define
$$
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_v=x_1\oplus x_2\oplus \cdots\oplus x_v \oplus index(permutation(x_1,\ldots,x_v)),
$$
so at the end we xor the index of the permutation which changes if the $x_i$ are reordered.

Comment: How does this compare to my idea above?  E.g. recursively for any $i$, $x_i + x_{i+1} = x_i \oplus (x_i + x_{i+1} \mod 2^d)$, with the base case being $x_0 = x_0$.  Basically I mainly wonder about two aspects:  (1) sensitivity to order, and (2) speed.  As for (1) I think it implies reduced collisions; e.g. how likely is it for different numbers of different orders to eventually get same final number?